# Using lambda expression to get property OR type name

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

How can I adapt the method below to work when the lambda expression refers to the actual instance itself?

e.g. instead of

```
x => x.Name
```

the expression is

```
x => x
```

so if I had some class "Car" I could return the string "Car" instead of only being able to operate on its properties (e.g. Car.Colour)

The method:

```
public static string GetMemberName(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression is LambdaExpression)
            expression = ((LambdaExpression)expression).Body;

        if (expression is MemberExpression)
        {
            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
            if (memberExpression.Expression.NodeType ==
                ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            {
                return GetMemberName(memberExpression.Expression)
                       + "."
                       + memberExpression.Member.Name;
            }
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }


        if (expression is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression;

            if (unaryExpression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Convert)
                throw new Exception(string.Format(
                    "Cannot interpret member from {0}",
                    expression));
            return GetMemberName(unaryExpression.Operand);
        }
        throw new Exception(string.Format(
            "Could not determine member from {0}",
            expression));
    }
```

i.e. I want something like:

```
if (expression is SomeExpressionThatReturnsAnInstance)
{
    return (name of type of instance);
}
```

Comment: So you want to return `object` instead of `property`, is it ?

Comment: No, I want the name of the object's type, e.g. "Car"

Comment: *if I had some class "Car" I could return the string "Car" instead* --- `x.ToString()` or `x.GetType().Name`?

Comment: @TyCobb - nope, at this point I only have an expression. x.ToString() returns "x => x", and x.GetType().Name returns "Expression`1"

Comment: `x` should be your `Car` instance. Are you saying `x` is an expression itself?

Comment: Where is GetMemberName called from? I think you don't even need the expression. You could use TypeOf(T) where T is the type of x, assuming you are calling it like it usually is.

Comment: GetMemberName is called on a list of custom types that represent an error, each of which contains a LambdaExpression property (named "Property"). So it's called like so: GetMemberName(myCustomError.Property). Sometimes this Property refers to an actual Member, sometimes it refers to the type.

Comment: If @Simon MᶜKenzie's answer is not the correct one (though i also understand the question like he does), can you give a couple of input-expected output pairs, so that we can understand better your requirements?

Comment: @Mathew please create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've traced this back to the construction of the Expression. It doesn't really contain any instance information, and no way to get the type name.

```
static Expression<Func<object, object>> thisObject = x => x;
```

So there's no way that a type name can be derived from an Expression that doesn't even have a type (other than object).

The method used to generate an expression that returns a property name:

```
LambdaExpression BuildExpression(Type rootType, string propertyName)
    {
        try
        {
            var properties = propertyName.Split('.');
            ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(rootType, "x");
            Expression expr = arg;
            foreach (string property in properties)
            {
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = rootType.GetProperty(property);
                if (propertyInfo == null)
                    return null;
                expr = Expression.Property(expr, propertyInfo);
                rootType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
            }
            return Expression.Lambda(expr, arg);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand, you said that code like `x => x.Name` works. It can't work this way.

Comment: @Mathew, how you use this `BuildExpression`? You can't convert from `LambdaExpression` to `Expression<Func<object, object>>`

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding, but a direct `x => x` will be a `ParameterExpression`. Just add an additional test under your existing `is MemberExpression` test:

```
if (expression is MemberExpression)
{
    // As-is
}
// New condition
if (expression is ParameterExpression)
{
    return expression.Type.Name;
}
```

Using this code:

```
class Car { public string Color { get; set; }}
```

```
Expression<Func<Car, string>> expr1 = x => x.Color;
Expression<Func<Car, Car>> expr2 = x => x;

Console.WriteLine(GetMemberName(expr1));
```

```
> Color
```

```
Console.WriteLine(GetMemberName(expr2));
```

```
> Car
```

Comment: methinks in OP _x => x_ not _()=>x_, so your solution possibly wrong

Comment: expression.NodeType is ExpressionType.Lambda

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that expression like *x=>x*, so you even not need see in body, just get parameters like

```
((LambdaExpression)expression).Parameters.First().Type.Name
```

also you can also add condition like

```
if(expression is ParameterExpression){
    return ((ParameterExpression)expression).Type
}
```

Comment: ((LambdaExpression)expression).Parameters[0].Type.Name returns "Object"

Comment: @Mathew how you call it?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use generics for more information!
public static string GetMemberName<T, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression)
    {
        if (expression is LambdaExpression)
            expression = ((LambdaExpression)expression).Body;

        if (expression is MemberExpression)
        {
            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
            if (memberExpression.Expression.NodeType ==
                ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            {
                return GetMemberName(memberExpression.Expression)
                       + "."
                       + memberExpression.Member.Name;
            }
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }

        //Magic part...
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(TValue))
        {
             return typeof(T).Name;
        }

        if (expression is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression;

            if (unaryExpression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Convert)
                throw new Exception(string.Format(
                    "Cannot interpret member from {0}",
                    expression));
            return GetMemberName(unaryExpression.Operand);
        }
        throw new Exception(string.Format(
            "Could not determine member from {0}",
            expression));
    }
```